# Print the output of an interactive command in a shell script

Tags: command-line, terminal, freebsd, monitoring, cgi

I am writing a CGI script to monitor the system state, so the information must be outputted to the terminal with `echo` or `cat`. The problem is, `systat` is an interactive command, so it doesn't print anything to the screen.

I tried `systat | echo` and `systat | cat`, but the former gives nothing, whereas the latter behaves identically as `systat`.

**Edit**

OK, let me clarify. Basically, I'm asking for a shell script, say `monitor.sh`. When executed with `./monitor.sh`, it would start a new process, output the result of `systat`, and then exit.

It should look something like this:

```
root@HPC:~/playground # ./monitor.sh
                    /0   /1   /2   /3   /4   /5   /6   /7   /8   /9   /10
     Load Average   >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> 12.0

                    /0%  /10  /20  /30  /40  /50  /60  /70  /80  /90  /100
root           calc XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
root           calc XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
root           calc XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
root           calc XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
root           calc XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
root           calc XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
root           calc XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
root           calc XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
root           calc XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
root           calc XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
root           calc XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
root           calc XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
root@HPC:~/playground #
```

Comment: What do you mean that it doesn't print anything to the screen? `systat` sends data to stdout when I run it on my FreeBSD machine including that of the sub-commands.

Comment: @NasirRiley Sorry for the confusion! More precisely, I want the characters to be outputted to `stdout`, because this is how CGI scripts deliver content to its clients (most likely Web browsers).

Comment: If you are just using the `systat` command ny itself then it already sends everything to `stdout`. I'm not clear on what you're trying to do or what you are not able to achieve. Can you provide more information on what it is that you are doing and what you expect to happen?

Comment: What happens when you just run ```systat``` from the script?

Comment: @G-Man The terminal window is occupied by the output of `systat`, until I press Ctrl + C. I guess at this time `systat` is running interactively

Comment: Do you need to send any commands to systat?

Comment: @JeffSchaller No, I don't. Simply printing out the bar chart is enough.

Comment: I should have used slightly more generic word; it sounds like you need to send Control-C to cause systat to exit?

Comment: @JeffSchaller Ah yeah that's true. I'm unaware of other methods to exit it. I think `systat` is just like `top`: both won't exit unit you send a signal.

Comment: @nalzok Both `systat` and `top` have options for automatically terminating after a number of iterations of output. Have you tried using this?

Comment: @Kusalananda No, I didn't know that before! I did some searching and realized `top` has `-d1` for running one iteration and exit, but I cannot find such an option for `systat`. Could you please point it out for me?

Comment: @nalzok I don't have a FreeBSD system at hand, but maybe something like `systat -q` or something similar to exit at once? I don't know if that makes it output _nothing_ or not though.

Comment: @Kusalananda It says `systat: q: unknown request` :(

Comment: Your question says “it [should] start a new process, output the result of `systat`, and then exit.” and “The problem is, `systat` is an interactive command, so it doesn't print anything to the screen.” When asked to clarify that, you admitted that it ***does*** print normal `systat` output to the screen, and that the problem is that it doesn’t exit. OK, we all make mistakes. But when you say something that’s not right, and we draw your attention to it, you should [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete (i.e., say what you mean).

Answer (score 1):

The [man page for `systat` on FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=systat) says,

- A “global” command interpreter processes all keyboard input.
- The **`quit`** command is interpreted by the “global” command interpreter. 
  It tells `systat` to exit.

  - The **`quit`** command may be abbreviated to **`q`**.
- “display commands” may be provided on the command line,
  preceded by a **`-`**. 
  (It is not made explicitly clear
  whether **`quit`** qualifies as a “display command”.)

So, it’s disappointing that `systat -q` doesn’t work. 
Other things to try:

- `systat -quit`
- `(sleep 5; echo quit) | systat`

  - (You may need to enter that as `sh -c '(sleep 5; echo quit) | systat'`.)
  - Or you may need to do `(sleep 5; echo :quit) | systat`
    or `sh -c '(sleep 5; echo :quit) | systat'`. 
    (Note the addition of the **`:`**.)
- `systat& sleep 5; kill "$!"`

  - (You may need to enter that as `sh -c 'systat& sleep 5; kill "$!"'`.)

You may need to adjust the sleep time to get the result that you want.